# Why am I getting sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object instead of the data in the sqlite table?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a table name `tower` and added two columns in it `towerid` and `towername` it contains data such as (1, Legacy).

```
class Tower(db.Model):
    towerid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    towername = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
```

```
class towerdata(Resource):
    def post(self):
        towerdatas = request.form
        towername = towerdatas.get('towername')
        addtowernames = Tower(towername=towername)
        db.session.add(addtowernames)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message': 'Tower added succesfully !!'})
```

Now I want to get the data of this table using Flask rest api

```
class gettower(Resource):
    def get(self):
        addtowernames = Tower.query.all()
        print(addtowernames)
        toweroutput = []
        for tower in addtowernames:
            toweroutput.append({
            'towerid': Tower.towerid,
            'towername':Tower.towername,
            })
        print(toweroutput)
        return jsonify({'message':'the towers'})
```

But in the output instead of `[<Tower 1>] [{'towerid': 1, 'towername': Legacy}]` I am geeting this

```
[<Tower 1>]
[{'towerid': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x00000138F32D7630>, 'towername': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x00000138F32D76D0>}]
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2021 15:46:31] "GET /towers HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The start of the code is

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import uuid # for public id
from  werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
# imports for PyJWT authentication
import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import wraps
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from flask_restful import Api
# creates Flask object
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
#app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your secret key'
# database name
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///main.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

# creates SQLALCHEMY object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

please help

Comment: In `gettower.get()`: `'towerid': Tower.towerid, 'towername':Tower.towername` should be `towerid: tower.towerid, towername: tower.towername`, i.e, `tower` with a lowercase `t`. You are referencing the class attribute, not the instance attribute.

Comment: Thank you, It was very helpful I thought we have to use the class `Tower`, not the table `tower`.

Comment: I'm doing a review of this question. For completeness, @SuperShoot can you provide your comment as an answer?

Comment: I had to derive a tip out of the answer from @SuperShoot for a similar symptom in a problem.